# How to show PIC cycles in MPLAB when using PICKit?

Tags: pic, timer, pickit

The MPLAB SIM has a nice stopwatch that shows the cycle count. But when using a PICKit 3, the stopwatch is not there. Any suggestions on how to bring this function back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stopwatch is only available with the simulator. You have to use other techniques if you are using a debugger, such as cycle counting, or outputting a pulse at the beginning and end of the code sequence, and using a scope to measure the time between the pulses.

This sort of question is best asked on the Microchip forums.

Comment: Thanks. I got the time using your second method, the scope, which is very quick. A 16 bit timer for cycle counting may be a better long term solution, but that needs some configuration that takes time...